# How to compare different types using hamcrest

Tags: java, hamcrest

I try to compare different types with hamcrest. But I don't understand, how I have to build my own `Matcher` for the following problem:

```
String[] exp = new String[]{"x", "y", "z"};
DAO[] cur = getFromExternalWebservice();
Assert.assertThat("wrong strings", exp, Matchers.arrayContainingInAnyOrder(cur));
```

`cur` is an array of the following class:

```
class DAO {
  public String id;
  public String name;
}
```

The test above should actually compare the `Strings` within `exp` and the `name` property of the `DAO` objects within the array `cur`. I cannot change something on `DAO` (like adding a `toString()` method).

I can transform the results from the webservice into a `names` array, which I send to the Matcher like this:

```
String names[] = new String[cur.length];
for (int i = 0; i < cur.length; i++) {
   names[i] = cur[i].name;
}
Assert.assertThat("wrong strings", exp, Matchers.arrayContainingInAnyOrder(names));
```

But this is ugly, how I can build a `Matcher` which compares the `Strings` without any copy of data?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a first idea:

```
public class IsIn extends BaseMatcher<String> {

   class DAOIterator implements Iterable<String>, Iterator<String> {
        private final DAO[] collection;
        private int idx;

        public DAOIterator(DAO[] elements) {
            this.collection = elements;
            idx = 0;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return (this.collection.length > this.idx);
        }

        @Override
        public String next() {
            return this.collection[this.idx++].name;
        }

        @Override
        public Iterator<String> iterator() {
            return new DAOIterator(this.collection);
        }
    }

    private final DAO[] collection;

    public IsIn(DAO[] elements) {
        this.collection = elements;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object o) {
        for (DAO d : this.collection) {
            if (o == null ? d.name == null : o.equals(d.name)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description buffer) {
        buffer.appendText("one of ");
        buffer.appendValueList("{", ", ", "}", new DAOIterator(this.collection));
    }

}
```

Call this on JUnit testcase:

```
String[] exp = new String[]{"x", "y", "z"};
DAO[] cur = getFromExternalWebservice();
Assert.assertThat("wrong strings", Arrays.asList(exp), Matchers.everyItem(new IsIn(cur)));
```